# Bash unable to assign variable

Tags: linux, bash, slurm

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --partition=standard
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem=100G
USEAGE="metascript.sh <wd> <wd1>"
source ~/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate assembly
wd=$1
wd1=$2
cd $wd
cd $wd1 
for f in SRR*/ ; do
  [[ -e $f ]] || continue
  SRR=${f::-1}
  cd ../..
  jdid=$(sbatch -J FirstQC_$SRR ./pipelines/preprocessingbowtietrinity/FirstFastqc.sh $wd $wd1 $SRR)
  #echo ${jdid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'
  jobid=${jdid[0]}
  jobid1=${jobid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'
  #echo $jobid1
```

Hi all just having issues with my bash scripting, so I can print the line ${jdid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]+' however when I assign it to a variable it is unable to return anything.

Comment: Are you expecting to feed `${jobid[0]` to `grep` and capture the output in `jobid1`? That's `jobid1=$( echo "${jobid[0]}" | grep -o '[0-9]\+' )`.

Comment: `jdid` is a string.  There's no benefit in treating it like an array.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to extract just the job ID from the output of `sbatch`, you can also use `sbatch`'s `--parsable` argument. See [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_parsable) in the documentation.

```
jdid=$(sbatch --parsable -J FirstQC_$SRR ./pipelines/preprocessingbowtietrinity/FirstFastqc.sh $wd $wd1 $SRR)
```

and `jdij` will only contain the job ID if the cluster is not part of a federation.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   jobid1=${jobid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'
> ```
>
> I can print the line ${jdid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]+' however when I assign it to a variable it is unable to return anything.

In order to assign the output of a pipeline to a variable or insert it into a command line for any other purpose, you have [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) at hand:

```
  jobid1=`echo ${jobid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'`
```

Of course, with `bash` this is better written as:

```
  jobid1=`<<<${jobid[0]} grep -o '[0-9]\+'`
```

Comment: With `bash`, you don't need `grep` at all. `[[ ${jobid[0]} =~ ([0-9]+) ]]; jobid1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

Comment: With any shell (written after about 1996), this is better written `jobid=$( ... )`.  Backticks are dead.

Comment: You seem to confuse _old-style_ with _dead_; the documentation does not confirm your death certificate.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the issue is printing the line ${jdid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]+' as your question.
2. Just put the line in double quotation marks and it will work out.
3. Here is a little test i made:

```
jobid1="{jobid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'"
echo $jobid1
```

- the out put is  `{jobid[0]}|grep -o '[0-9]\+'`